# How do I mock this method chain in Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jestjs, enzyme

```
zoomOut(callback) {
        // Zooms out the current screen
        this.view.current.zoomOut(300).done(() => {
            (hasCallback(callback)) && callback();
        });
    }
```

I'm trying to test the function above but I keep getting the following error:

> TypeError: this.view.current.zoomOut(...).done is not a function

How can I mock this method chain in Jest?

Comment: This is not a method chain, it just invokes the method on a deeply nested object.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
const mockZoomOut = jest.fn(() => ({ done(cb) { cb(); } }));
const mockThis = {
    view: {
        current: {
            zoomOut: mockZoomOut,
        },
    },
};

test('it does', () => {
    const cb = jest.fn();
    zoomOut.apply(mockThis, [cb]);
    expect(mockZoomOut).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(cb).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

See [Jest Mock Functions](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions) and [fn.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

If you are testing the behaviour of the class as a whole, then you could set up the instance that you are testing to have `this.view.current.zoomOut` be `mockZoomOut` somehow.

Comment: For anyone interested, one such method by which to achieve having `this.view.current.zoomOut` be `mockZoomOut` is Dependency Injection.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to BudgieInWA, I was able to solve this problem by returning `done`.

**For those who are testing a React component with Enzyme, here's how you can do it:**

```
it('should call callback', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Zoom {...minProps}/>);
    const instance = wrapper.instance();

    const callback = jest.fn();

    instance.view = {
        current: {
            zoomOut: jest.fn(() => {
                return {
                    done: jest.fn((callback) => {
                        callback();
                    })
                };
            })
        }
    };

    expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
    instance.zoomOut(callback);
    expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```